# Does a Lebesgue measurable set E exist with this property?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, radon-nikodym

Does there exist a  Lebesgue measurable set $E$ such that for all $n>0$ $m(E \bigcap [0,n])=\frac{n}{2}$?

I think we can't have such this set, because if so, then we can write $E$ as a countable union of the intersections
$E \bigcap [0,n]$ and then pass the measure with monotonicity we get a contradiction.

I am not sure whether my argument is correct, any idea or hint is appreciated

Comment: can you elaborate on where the contradiction would be? I am not yet getting it...

Comment: Is $n$ a  positive integer or any positive number?

Comment: The OP talks about "countable union" so $n$ should be an integer. Although it should have been mentioned.

Comment: Is $n$ a natural number or real?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume $n = x$ is real, because otherwise the question is trivial.

First, if you know the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, then the answer is obviously no, because the condition on $E$ implies that $E$ (or equivalently, $\chi_E$) has *no* Lebesgue points.

Otherwise, you can prove it directly this way. Let's focus attention on $E_1 = (0,1] \cap E$. We have $m(E_1) = 1/2$. Thus $E_1$ is contained in some open set $U \subseteq (0, +\infty)$ such that $m(U) \leq 3/4$ (using the definition of Lebesgue measure via outer measure).

Now write $U$ as a countable disjoint union of intervals $I_k$. We have $m(E \cap I_k) = \frac{1}{2}m(I_k)$ by the hypothesis on $E$. So
$$1/2 = m(E_1) = \sum_k m(E_1 \cap I_k) \leq \sum_k m(E \cap I_k) = \sum_k \frac{1}{2}m(I_k) = \frac{1}{2}m(U) \leq 3/8.$$

Comment: The idea of the contradiction in your proof is clear and simple but can we get a contradiction using the uniqueness of Radon-Nikodym derivative?